# replacing a string with multiple $ symbol in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, string, str-replace

I am trying to replace a string with multiple `$` symbol in JavaScript using replace function. But all of the `$` symbols are not getting written.

For eg:

```js
var a = "xyz";
a = a.replace("xyz", "$$$");
console.log(a)
```

Output:

```
$$
```

Comment: The `$` character is special in replacement strings. You have to use two `$` characters for every one you actually want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `$` symbol has special meaning when used inside [`String.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter). You can escape it by *doubling* it:

```js
var a = "xyz";
a = a.replace("xyz", "$$$$$$");
console.log(a)
```

Comment: but even for "$$$$$" (5 dollar symbols) it prints "$$$" (3 dollar symbols)

Comment: Yes. To be more precise, the $ symbol needs to be followed by certain characters e.g. digits or $ symbol to have an effect (see doc). The 5th $ symbol in your example is not substituted and displayed as-is.

Answer (score 0):

`$` is a special character. so you have to use additional $ for each of them

```js
var a = "xyz";
a = a.replace("xyz", "$$$$$$");
console.log(a)
```